# How to get current date using widget TextClock in android?

Tags: android

I have create a TextClock widget to show the running time.

In Layout

```
<TextClock
    android:id="@+id/timerr"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:textSize="50sp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  />
```

In activity , created reference

```
    textClock = (TextClock) findViewById(R.id.timerr);
```

Setted format for both 12 hours and 24 hour format

For 24 hour

```
    textClock.setFormat12Hour(null);
    textClock.setFormat24Hour("HH:mm:ss");
```

for 12 hour,

```
   textClock.setFormat12Hour("hh:mm:ss a");
   textClock.setFormat24Hour(null);
```

Now,i need to get the current date while clicked the button along with the time,but i need to display only the time not the date in UI.

it is possible to get the Date along with time,someone help plz..
Thanks in advance.

This is how my UI looks...

https://i.stack.imgur.com/oQ5VR.png

Comment: if you want the current time, can't you just get a calendar instance and then jus tset the parameters of TextClock?

Comment: Cannot get current date from TextClock widget because there are methods to get . instead you can use Calendar object. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextClock.html

Comment: Date now = new Date();
Date alsoNow = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
String nowAsString = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").format(now);

Comment: Thanks for ur response...In my UI i have to show the running time with second,when login button is click have to save time and the date

Comment: You can get the date using TextClock widget. Please find the code snippet below:  

12 hours format:
textClock.setFormat12Hour("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm aa");
textClock.setFormat24Hour(null);

24 hours format:
textClock.setFormat12Hour(null);
textClock.setFormat24Hour("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm");

Answer (score 10):

Just use the format to retrieve date time

`(dd:Mm:yyyy:hh:mm:ss a)`  --> 06-02-2018:08:13:57 PM

`(dd:MMM:yyyy:hh:mm:ss a)` --> 06-Feb-2018:08:13:57 PM

```
<TextClock
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:format12Hour="dd-MMM-yyyy:hh:mm:ss a"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal" />
```

Comment: that is not effect use dd-MMM-yyyy only hh:mm:ss a work,please update it

Comment: @shuabing it is working for me, just have to define it in java

Answer (score 1):

You cannot get current date from time widget. But, using `Date`, `Calendar` with `SimpleDateFormat` is proper way to get currentdate.

1.

`Date()` + `SimpleDateFormat()`

```
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");

Date date = new Date();

System.out.println(dateFormat.format(date));
```

2

`Calender()` + `SimpleDateFormat()`

```
 DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd");

 Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();

 System.out.println(dateFormat.format(cal.getTime()));
```

[For more details refer this link](http://www.mkyong.com/java/java-how-to-get-current-date-time-date-and-calender/)

Comment: Thanks for ur response...In my UI i have to show the running time with second,when login button is click have to save time and the date

Comment: Then try to use date picker http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_datepicker_control.htm

Comment: ok. I assume that you want to display the login time with date correct . I have a doubt that you storing your login time? If you you are store your login time in your db then save login time with date. Create a Textview below your time and display your date there.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to show date like example Wed, 27-Oct

use android:format12Hour="EE, dd-MMM"

as below for example

```
                 <TextClock
                  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:format12Hour="EE, dd-MMM"
                  android:textColor="@color/gray_100"
                  android:textSize="15sp"
                  android:layout_gravity="center"
                  android:padding="5dp"
                  android:textStyle="bold" />
```